# SpringMVC Contextloader don't start

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am newer to spring.

I use intellij for developying

first i create a maven webapp, then add spring mvc framework support
this is my project structure

[image]

but when the project starting, I don't find any log about spring

```
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/xujifa/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_demoweb
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /var/lib/tomcat8
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/xujifa/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_demoweb/conf/logging.properties
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/xujifa/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/tomcat/Unnamed_demoweb
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/var/lib/tomcat8
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat8/temp
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/idea/bin:/opt/idea/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.579 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.592 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.596 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.605 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 534 ms
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.8
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.690 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.696 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:51.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 92 ms
    Connected to server
    [2016-12-10 04:20:52,002] Artifact demoweb:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    10-Dec-2016 16:20:52.776 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    [2016-12-10 04:20:52,848] Artifact demoweb:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

any one can tell me how to resolve it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have find the problem

There was something about my artifacts